# Подключить файлы css cordova

Tags: css, cordova

Пытаюсь подключить свои css файлы в index.html проекта cordova стандартным способом

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/mdl/material.min.css">
```

при эмуляции на андроид устройстве не работают стили этого файла.
Если просмотреть через браузер, то ссылка не ведет к этому файлу (not found)
Как решить?Кто сталкивался?с этим?

Comment: Вы уверены, что путь верный? Может стоит указать так: `href="lib/mdl/material.min.css"` ?

Comment: простите за тупость.вы правы